# Docker ECS compose: How to pick VPC, domain, security group, etc?

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm looking at the documentation for ECS contexts in docker, but I can't seem to find more than a couple of articles.

Seems like a great idea, but I'm now wondering how to pick the VPC of the ECS cluster, and who knows what else...

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen [this page](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/)? For example [here](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/#using-existing-aws-network-resources) you can read how to pick a VPC.

Specifically:

`Use x-aws-vpc as a top-level element in your Compose file to set the ARN of a VPC when deploying a Compose application.`

[This link](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-compose-examples/) includes examples of how you would use these extensions. For example,  for VPC and the cluster name it would be:

```
x-aws-vpc: "vpc-25435e"
x-aws-cluster: "ClusterName"

services:
  app:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Comment: Can you expand this answer to include some more details?  Generally SO discourages answers that are just links, even if it's to the official Docker documentation.

Comment: I added a couple of examples in the post. I posted links because "and who knows what else" left the question a bit open ended IMO.